# Ubuntu 16.04 MySqlDumb backup script

Tags: command-line, scripts, backup

Running ubuntu 16.04
My script currently looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Backup from bas database
mysqldump -u root -p[Password] bas > /home/beginstation/SqlBackup/LOI.sql
```

When I check my files and try to copy it I get a "No such file or directory" error message. This command does allow me to copy the files and doesn't give me the error message:

```
mysqldump -u root -p[Password]bas > /home/beginstation/SqlBackup/LOI.sql
```

Running the script through putty with this command: `Bash /home/beginstation/Test.sh`

I was wondering if anyone had any idea on how to fix this

Comment: Letter B in `bash` is capital when you run it?

Comment: What if you add `2> /home/beginstation/SqlBackup/errors`? Any `mysqldump` errors will be written to that file, so you can see what is going on.